# ¿Cómo hacer más eficiente un loop para crear una data.frame a partir de otra data.frame en R?

Tags: r, funciones, bucle-for, bucles, programación-funcional

Tengo una pequeña función infija para calcular el crecimiento entre observaciones.

```
#La base de datos de prueba
test <- data.frame(a=c(101,202,301), b=c(123,214,199), h=c(134, 217, 205))

#La función
`%grow%` <- function(x,y) {
    options(digits=3)   # Para controlar el número de dígitos desplegados en el resultado
    num <- y-x
    den <- x
    return(num/den*100)
    }
```

Para guardar las observaciones, creo otra base de datos en blanco: (Este es el primer punto que me interesa hacer más eficiente, ya que crear una base de datos simplemente como `test2 <- data.frame()` simplemente no daba resultados)

```
test2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(test), ncol=ncol(test)-1))
```

La naturaleza del problema es simple, ya que la nueva base de datos tendrá dos columnas, así que no se me ocurrió otra cosa que iterar después de haber intentado `lapply` y `apply`sin éxito (Quizás estoy omitiendo algo, así que sería bueno saberlo)

```
for (i in 1:ncol(test)) {
    test2[,i] <- cbind(test[,i]%grow%test[,(i+1)])
    }
test2
```

Funciona casi correctamente ya que, aunque despliega correctamente la nueva base de datos, me arroja un error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , (i + 1)) : undefined columns selected
> test2
      X1   X2
1  21.78 8.94
2   5.94 1.40
3 -33.89 3.02
```

Por tanto, mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Cómo iterar correctamente para evitar el error anterior?
2. ¿Cómo iterar para llenar una base de datos a partir de `nombre <- data.frame()`, es decir, una `data.frame` vacía?
3. ¿Es posible utilizar alguna función de la familia `apply` en un problema como éste?

Gracias de antemano por sus consejos y respuestas :D

PD: También acepto respuestas con `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema que tienes es tipográfico: `for (i in 1:ncol(test))` debiera ser más bien `for (i in 1:ncol(test2))`, el primer `data.frame` tiene una columna más por lo que cuando `i=3`, obviamente `test2[,i]` será inválido. Corrigiendo esto funcionará todo perfectamente, pero aprovecho para hacerte algunas observaciones:

```
`%grow%` <- function(x,y) {
    options(digits=3)   # Para controlar el número de dígitos desplegados en el resultado
    num <- y-x
    den <- x
    return(num/den*100)
    }
```

La voy a rescribir así:

```
`%grow%` <- function(x,y) {
    (y-x) / x * 100
}
```

- `options(digits=3)` es una configuración para establecer el número de digitos significativos que queremos ver en pantalla, es una configuración global de la sesión de trabajo, no afecta los datos sino como se van a representar cuando los veamos por consola, no tiene sentido que esté dentro de la función
- Esto es una cuestión personal, prefiero evitar definir variable cuando no es estrictamente necesario
- Evito el uso del `return`, R siempre retorna la última expresión evaluada de una función

Por otro lado, no es necesario usar `cbind()` en este caso: `test2[,i] <- test[,i] %grow% test[,(i+1)]` ya que la función retorna un vector asignable directamente a la columnas de `test2`.

Con respecto a usar una función de la familia `*apply` sin duda puedes, el tema es que obviamente no puedes iterar sobre el `data.frame` original por que tiene tres columna y lo que buscas es obtener 2, una forma de hacerlo es directamente con `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:(ncol(test)-1), function(i) test[,i] %grow% test[,(i+1)])
```

El truco es iterar sobre un un numérico que va de 1 a la cantidad de columnas menos 1.  También puedes usar la versión "segura" de `sapply`:

```
vapply(1:(ncol(test)-1), function(i) test[,i] %grow% test[,(i+1)], FUN.VALUE=c(numeric(nrow(test))))
```

Ten en cuenta que el retorno es una matriz, pero puedes transformarla en un `data.frame` con `as.data.frame()`.

Con estas funciones te evitas la necesidad de crear un nuevo `data.frame`. La idea de crear un `data.frame` o matriz vacía, surge por que muchas veces tanto en los ciclos explícitos (for, while) como en los implícitos (`*apply`) se hacen operaciones que implican muchas veces ir copiando el mismo `data.frame` por cada ciclo, lo que efectivamente es un costo enorme de CPU.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda aquí y de forma personal. Excelente inicio de año.